# how to set username to python request explicitly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, request, python-requests

Trying to set token and username to python `request.get` session, so that next consecutive `session.post` must have both the session and username. I am able to set the token, however I tried setting the username, but next post call doesn't carry it.

`request.session['account_token'] = encoded_token` - works

`request.user = username` - doesn't work

Expected result should be - with the get call, I should be able to set the username and encoded token to the session and using these set values next post call should be able to authenticate the request and proceed as intended.

Comment: Well that is not how you set the request.user. You do that by calling `login`.

Comment: Unpacking @DanielRoseman's comment:  middleware typically controls the `request.user` in django.  You'll have to make sure your middleware is configured correctly for your use case and also that sessions are configured correctly in settings.